# Android DatePicker only show the calendar

Tags: android, android-widget, android-datepicker

Android's new DatePicker widget shows a large date text at the top, but I really don't need it.  It's wasting a lot of space.  Is there a way to hide that, and show only the calendar below.

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with that extra space instead?

Comment: For one, the buttons I added below the widget can't be shown on a small screen like a phone's.  I had to wrap my layout in a ScrollView so the user could scroll down and see other things below the widget.

Comment: @PolyBug did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use CalendarView, which does not show the header and has all the same methods.